# JSF - How to save managedBean state when session times out?

Tags: session, jsf, session-timeout

I am working for a client that has it's own session management system in case of idle timeouts. What happens is the following :

1. User stays idle for the set amount of time.
2. Session times out redirecting to login page
3. User enters credentials and is redirected back to where he was.

Now the above process is handled by passing a POST request passing the **javax.faces.ViewState** to the session management system. However, in case of timeouts it needs only 8K of data in the request to process and redirect. But since my managed bean is saving a lot of data (banking app, need to keep track of the calculations!) the size of the request is high (around 20K) due to which redirection fails.

So is there any way I can somehow save the ViewState? Or better, any way I can prevent the timeout? Something like keeping the session alive?

All my managed beans have a `session` scope.

EDIT: Just in case required, the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` context-param in web.xml is set to `client` for performance purposes.

EDIT: Did a trace of the flow using HttpWatch and found out that **javax.faces.ViewState** is taking up 18kB of the total 22kB of size of the POST request. So my aim is narrowed down to reducing the size of ViewState. Any way to I can do this ?

Comment: I understand that you are redirecting to the original URL with all request parameters as query string in the redirect URL and that the state saving method is set to `client` instead of `server`?

Comment: State saving method is client, yes. And the redirect does not occur through my application. The server is configured to auto redirect to the URL by sending a POST request as I mentioned.

Comment: State saving has nothing to do with session scoped beans and session timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

State saving only keeps the data associated with the current view. Your problem here is that the session scoped beans are lost. I suggest two ways of solving the problem:

1) Implement a HttpSessionListener and in its sessionDestroyed() method get the beans, serialize them and store them in a database row associated with the current user. When the user logs in again you can fetch the beans, deserialize them and put them in the user's session.

2) Implement ajax poll that will ping the server in a specific period and this way the session will not timetout. You could achive this using Richfaces JSF library that has a built-in JSF component for ajax poll.